# DataReader value row by row

Tags: c#

I know I can use `while (dr.Read()) {...}` but that loops every field on my table, I want to retrieve all the values from the first row, and then second... and so on.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID--------------Value1--------------Value2------------------Value3
1               hello               hello2                  hello3
2               hi1                 hi2                     hi3
3               hey1                hey2
```

I want output as :  hello hi1 hey1

From the comment below:

flag

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From DataLogger1 where Time BETWEEN '"+DateTimePicker.Value+"' AND '"+DateTimePicker1.Value+"' "; 
cmd.Connection = conn1;
conn1.Open(); 
SqlCeDataReader rd= cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
while(rd.Read()) 
{ 
     Globals.Tags.Xarrray[0].Value=rd[2].ToString(); 
     Globals.Tags.Xarrray[1].Value=rd[2].ToString(); 
     Globals.Tags.Xarrray[2].Value=rd[2].ToString(); 
     Globals.Tags.Xarrray[3].Value=rd[2].ToString(); 
     Globals.Tags.Xarrray[4].Value=rd[2].ToString();
```

Comment: `DataReader.Read()` loops on *rows*, not on *columns*. It already does exactly what you're asking for. What's your problem? Got any sample code?

Comment: i want to store Value 1 column value as:  textbox1.text=hello textboxw.text=hi1 textbox3.text=hey1

Comment: do you want to convert every column into row ?
there is in consistency between you explanation and your expected output

Comment: If you have code that is not working and seek help to fix it, then it is logical to provide that code, otherwise.....

Comment: @sacpat moved your code in the question itself. Next time press [edit] and change the question. Code in comments is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so you want first *three records* which all are from the *2nd column*:

> i want to store Value 1 column value as: textbox1.text=hello
>   textboxw.text=hi1 textbox3.text=hey1

Something like this:

```
using (var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
  if (reader.Read()) 
    textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1)); // hello

  if (reader.Read()) 
    textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1)); // hi1

  if (reader.Read()) 
    textbox3.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1)); // hey1
}
```

Just *three* conseq. reads, no `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

To get:

```
hello hi1 hey1
```

just ignore the other columns (or don't select them if you don't need them) and only output Value1.  Don't put a line break in if you really want to keep it on the same line.

Comment: i want to store Value 1 column value as:  textbox1.text=hello textboxw.text=hi1 textbox3.text=hey1 using datareader

Answer (score 0):

You can read your input line by line, fill some structures with the data and then extract what you want using linq.

You can define a structure like:

```
class Data
{
    public string Id;
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
    public string Value3;
}
```

Then read all your data.

```
var allData = new List<Data>();
while(dr.Read())
{
    var d = new Data { Id = dr.GetString(0), Value1 = dr.GetString(1), Value2 = dr.GetString(2), Value = dr.GetString(3) };
    allData.Add(d);
}

var result = allData.Select(x => x.Value1);
```

Result is an IEnumerable< string > which contains your values. You can then do whatever you want with the values.